Inserting a specific content after all items in enumerate

The text above is as desired, but I want the rule to be inserted after all items automatically
My MWE
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{enumerate}
    
    \item Text 1 \rule{3em}{0.4pt}
    
    \item Text 2 \rule{3em}{0.4pt}
    
\end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}


Should it be always a rule of 3em or better filling the rest of the line?

@Fran. It should be of specific length

You can use LaTeX3's argument processor to split the enumerate environment body at every instance of \item, and then process them separately.

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

% Capture original enumerate environment; call is oldenumerate
\NewCommandCopy{\oldenumerate}{\enumerate}
\NewCommandCopy{\endoldenumerate}{\endenumerate}

\NewDocumentCommand{\EndItem}{ }{\rule{3em}{0.4pt}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ProcessItem}{ m }{\IfBlankF{#1}{\item #1~\EndItem}}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{enumerate}{ O{} >{\SplitList{\item}} +b }{}{%
  \begin{oldenumerate}[#1]
    \ProcessList{#2}{\ProcessItem}
  \end{oldenumerate}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Something
  \item Something else
  \item Yet another thing
  \item Something different altogether
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label={\bfseries\alph*)}]
  \item Something
  \item Something else
  \item Yet another thing
  \item Something different altogether
\end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}


This solution works, but it is better be without modifying the original enumerate. It is also not possible to add spaces between items

@Al-MotasemAldaoudeyeh: Add spaces? Please elaborate.

In the source code, you cannot add spaces between items

If it does not have to be a \rule, but just something which looks like one, you could use the autopuncitems package:
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{autopuncitems} 
\setAPall{\_\_\_\_}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{enumerate}[autopunc]
\item Text 1 
\item Text 2 
\end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}



Something like that will do (if you don't have any special need):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\item #1 \rule{3em}{0.4pt}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{enumerate}
    
    \myitem{Text 1}
    
    \myitem{Text 2}
    
\end{enumerate}
    
\end{document}

